# Install Intel Ethernet W3100E on Ubuntu 20

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet, intel

I recently got an MSI GS66 Stealth 10SFS laptop on which I immediately installed an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Everything is working fine, except for the Ethernet RJ45 port (that is working and recognized as "Killer W3100" on Windows 10).

I read a few things about such problems and they all ended up using a more recent kernel. Mine is 5.4.20-52, which is on-par with the current 5.4.73 "longterm".

Is there anything I can do to be able to use my ethernet cable?

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux aldebaran 5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo lshw
...
   *-network UNCLAIMED
        description: Ethernet controller
        product: Intel Corporation
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:3d:00.0
        version: 02
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
        configuration: latency=0
        resources: memory:ad200000-ad2fffff memory:ad300000-ad303fff
...
```

```
$ sudo lshw -short | grep network
H/W path           Device       Class          Description
==========================================================
                                system         GS66 Stealth 10SFS (16V1.1)
/0/100/14.3        wlo1         network        Wi-Fi 6 AX201
/0/100/1d.6/0                   network        Intel Corporation
```

```
$ lspci -knn
...
3d:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3101] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0000]
```

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep intel
intel-media-va-driver:amd64     install
intel-microcode                 install
libdrm-intel1:amd64             install
libdrm-intel1:i386              install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up working after a couple of upgrade...